# I want to find a <span> tag that resides inside a <h1> tag that contains multiple <span> tags and get the text inside it

Tags: python, html, parsing, beautifulsoup

What I want to do is select the second span and grab its text to print it. 
Below is the HTML code and BeautifulSoup code

```
#HTML code

<h1 id="productTitle">
   <a href="https://www.example.com/product/">
       <span id="productBrand">BRAND</span>
   </a>
   <span>PRODUCT TITLE </span>
</h1>
```

```
#BeautifulSoup code

for h1 in soup.find_all('h1', id="productTitle"):
    productTitle = h1.find('span').text
    print(productTitle)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hopefully, not always, id should be unique meaning `find_all` is likely not required.

With bs4 4.7.1+ you can use :not to exclude the child span with an id

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

html = '''<h1 id="productTitle">
   <a href="https://www.example.com/product/">
         <span id="productBrand">BRAND</span>
   </a>
         <span>PRODUCT TITLE </span>
</h1>
'''
soup = bs(html, 'lxml')
print(soup.select_one('#productTitle span:not([id])').text)
```

You could also nth-child

```
print(soup.select_one('#productTitle span:nth-child(2)').text)
```

or

```
print(soup.select_one('#productTitle span:nth-child(even)').text)
```

or even an immediate sibling combinator to get `span` after child `a`

```
print(soup.select_one('#productTitle a + span').text)
```

or chained next_sibling

```
print(soup.select_one('#productTitle a').next_sibling.next_sibling.text)
```

Answer (score 0):

This gets all the fields you need within an `h1` tag :

**Python Code :**

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
text = '''
<h1 id="productTitle">
   <a href="https://www.example.com/product/">
         <span id="productBrand">BRAND</span>
   </a>
         <span>PRODUCT TITLE </span>
</h1>
'''
soup = BeautifulSoup(text,features='html.parser')
#BeautifulSoup code

for h1 in soup.find_all('h1', id="productTitle"):
    spans = h1.find_all('span')
    print('productBrand  == > {}'.format(spans[0].text))
    print('productTitle  == > {}'.format(spans[1].text))
```

**Get All Spans withing the h1 :**

```
for h1 in soup.find_all('h1', id="productTitle"):
    for i,span in enumerate(h1.find_all('span')):
      print('span {} == > {}'.format(i,span.text))
```

**Demo :**
[Here](https://repl.it/repls/UnrulyNarrowLeads)